# How to get accurate ListView height at runtime?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, height

I need to get accurate listView height at runtime.

When I use code below, height of each listItem is incorrect.

```
            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listview);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            params.height = totalHeight + listview.getDividerHeight()* (listAdapter.getCount() -1);
            listview.setLayoutParams(params);
            listview.requestLayout();
```

when I use getChild version, Height is accurate but total count is off...

```
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View childAt = listview.getChildAt(i);
            if (childAt == null)
                continue;

            int childH = childAt.getMeasuredHeight();
            total += childH;
        }
        int div = listview.getDividerHeight();
        total += (div * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));

        if (params.height != total) {
            getLogger().info("setting measured buttons list to height: " + total);
            params.height = total;
            listview.requestLayout();
            ViewParent parent = listview.getParent();
```

Have you run into this issue?

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to find the height of `listView` you can use

```
listView.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        listView.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, but I don't quite understand why. Can you explain why posting `listView.getHeight()` on the UI thread as you have done gives the desired result, but simply using `listView.getHeight()` by itself in 'onViewCreated' returns 0?

Comment: If you use `listView.getHeight()` in `onViewCreated` there is no guarantee that the `listView` has been drawn yet. If you call it in the way I've displayed here then it will be called once the `listView` has been drawn so you are able to get the correct height.

Comment: Dude! Your solution is so simple and the exactly correct, Tried a lot solution but none of them were giving the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

listItem.measure(0, 0);   parameters of measure 0,0 use first parameter MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) and second parameter MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)) follow this code

public static void getTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) 
    {

```
    ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int listWidth = listView.getMeasuredWidth();

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),

                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

Comment: I am writing same code .it work but my issue is in my listview each view height is diff. and in this code each view height is same return that's why last item of list is not display i.e. complete listview is not display ..

Comment: check this link here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197133/how-to-calculate-listview-height-of-different-height-listitem-in-android

Comment: **ANS**
use this 
mView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
on your code mView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));