# how to calculate listview height of different height listitem in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

**This code is work but the issue is in ListView each item of ListView is diff so last item of ListView is not display because big height ListView item get this space .**

**here is code:**

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView,DownloadAdapter adapter,LinearLayout layDownloads) {

ListAdapter mAdapter = adapter;

    int totalHeight = 0,h=0;
    int listWidth=listView.getMeasuredWidth();

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

    mView.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        h=mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1))+h;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
```

}

**Here is screen**

[image]

**please help me how to get height of listview of each cell and to to calculate heght of listview?
Thanks in advance..**

Comment: you can use listview in scroll view to scroll down and view all items

Comment: my listview in scrollview but issue is, on my screen the are 3 linear layout and each have diff listview thats why I have to set dynamically each listView height, So I m using this method to set the height of listview.

Comment: Why not considering this solution : have your items be the same default size showing a summary, then on click, expand a particular item ?

Comment: no I wont to display whole row of list

Answer (score 1):

your function replace by

```
public static void getTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int listWidth = listView.getMeasuredWidth();

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: works like a charm for me!
(i do have a listview inside a cardview)

Answer (score 0):

**ANS**
use this

mView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

on your code

mView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

Comment: try again replace this given code first( 0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) from (listWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)

Comment: it give 0 height of listview row

Comment: post your complet code and take again by change code it working fine on my